# Vagrant box ubuntu with jenkins cannot access home page

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, vagrant

Scenario

- Vagrant
- Puppet
- Puphpet
- Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS x32

I have my vhost working and everything fine but when I installed jenkins following this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu) I can't access to the jenkins home page

my jenkins.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xx@xxx.xxx
        ServerName ci.xxx.xxx
        ServerAlias ci
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

after I ran the commands:

```
$ a2ensite jenkins
Enabling site jenkins.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
$ service apache2 reload
$ apache2ctl restart
```

hosts file [in the host computer]
192.168.56.101       localhost jenkins.dev

but going to localhost:8080 or jenkins.dev:8080 nothing happens, only "This web page is not available" message

the jenkins.log

```
# cat /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Dec 23, 2014 4:03:37 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Dec 23, 2014 4:03:47 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.8
Dec 23, 2014 4:03:53 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Dec 23, 2014 4:03:56 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Dec 23, 2014 4:03:56 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Dec 23, 2014 4:03:57 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:20 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:20 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:23 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 46803
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:23 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Dec 23, 2014 4:05:23 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I will answer my own question :)

I just needed to forward the ports of vargant, so I modified the config.yaml file generated by puphpet looking the section like...

```
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        ...
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                ...
                6Z78RN0FAAN9:
                    host: '8080'
                    guest: '8080'
```

the I reload the vargant with:

```
vargant reload --provision
```

and now works fine, let's integrate :)